# IIS 8/C#.Net, intermittent unhandled exception 3005

Tags: debugging, iis, amazon-web-services, c#-2.0

This error does not happen all the time, but it happens randomly (how else to describe?) when requesting the web page multiple times.

I'm not entirely sure if this is an IIS issue or .Net issue.   We are running on Amazon AWS servers, and we are able to deploy our project to 1 older server (Windows Server 2012, IIS 8) - the application will never throw an error.

However, when we create a new server (either 2012 or 2012 R2) we start seeing this wierd issue.   We request our website multiple times, this error occurs randomly during this time.  This is reproducible over a few minutes, and we are constantly able to see this error come up.

```
Exception: (NullReferenceException) Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

StackTrace:   at System.Web.UI.Control.UnloadRecursive(Boolean dispose)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.UnloadRecursive(Boolean dispose)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.UnloadRecursive(Boolean dispose)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestCleanup()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.onlineorders_restaurantreceipt_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6e6b18b2\3b005822\App_Web_tfqgsomr.1.cs:line 0
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

We do not use a custom IHTTPHandler, and we wrapped all the code under Page_Load into a huge try-catch block.   Yet our try-catch is never encountered, so we are not sure where this error is happening.  I enabled failed-request tracing, and here is the compact version of the trace:

[Imgur URL to trace log data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFbc2.png)

Trying WinDbg or Debugging Tools did not result in any new information (same stack trace shows up).  Any help pointing me in the right direction would be great.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: As far as I knew, you really shouldn't be running .Net framework 2.0 on IIS 8+ as it is unpredictable.

Comment: Actually, we migrated the code to .Net 4 on the same server and we receive the exact same errors.  I will update the title, as its not only .Net 2 specific.

Comment: Possibly session related? What do the event log messages say?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/soulcyon/cf09963451e9f57f1354 

We tried disabling all the session-related code and turned off sessionState for the pages as well as web.config.   But no bueno.   I was able to generate some crash dumps, with help of debugging tools but I'm not too familiar with WinDbg commands to dig through.